# woocommerce - large number of variations for a variable product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a variable product with 3 attributes. The total number of variations generated is 900. This will make the admin page incredibly slow and hard to work with, so I need to find a workaround. I thought about replacing the dynamically generated dropdowns(for attribute values) with static ones, but the shopping cart expects to receive a variation number, which is non-existent in this case. I'd also like to mention that the variations are identical in all parameters, besides the attributes. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: The variations are being loaded with ajax in WooCommerce 2.4 (which is currently in beta) so that should be a major improvement.

Comment: Link : http://develop.woothemes.com/woocommerce/2015/07/woocommerce-2-4-beta-testing-begins/

Comment: There were improvements in WooCommerce 2.3 with variations but as someone else pointed out 2.4 will greatly improve variations as well.

Comment: 2.6, having more than a dozen of variations is still unsuable